# CPU frequency changes when AC power is lost

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86

I have a device with "supercapacitor" support. When the AC power is lost, supercapacitor provides power backup of ~2 mins. I observe CPU frequency by `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz` command are being dropped down when AC power is lost.

- AC power ON ==> Between 800 MHz to 1200 MHz
- AC POWER OFF ==> ~795 MHZ

How does kernel know that AC is lost, is there a dedicated event which is triggered?

Comment: Look into "ACPI"

Comment: Does your OS use tuned for performance optimization?

Comment: @zinsendorf I am using yocto based embedded OS, how can I verify it?